# RF electronics: transmission line transformer

Tags: rf, dac, balun

I got in charge of a schematic and I am checking its design.

There is a DAC EV12DS480A with differential RF output. I showed the method that is used to go from differential to the single-end:

[image]

I never used this configuration. For reference, it has different names as far as I searched about it: transmission line transformer/  transmission line balun/ current balun. SBTX2-113-2W+ is the chosen balun.

I downloaded the S3P files and I tried to simulate this configuration in AWR MWO (VSS: system simulation):
In AWR MWO, I put a source then used a hybrid 180 to resemble a DAC's output diffential ports then I used the balun to gro from differential to single-end connection as the main schemtic suggested.

[image]

The problem is that it does not work! The output power is heavily decreased after going from differential to single-end. I understand this configuration exists and it is used.

- I checked the touchstone (S3P) file with the ports name and I used the correct ones in the simulation.
- This is in the header of the touchstone S3P file:

"!Port-Pin Connections:PriD=PORT1, SecD=PORT2, Sec=PORT3 ."

and this from the datasheet:

[image]

I am kinda sure that I am connecting the right connection. and I have almost like -40 dB attenuation. However, if I connect the output differntial source to the balun in a voltage way, then I will have almost the same power level as I expected.

Do you have any idea?
Has anyone faced this configuration before? How did the simulation go?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replicate this in your simulator: -

[image]

Pictures and explanation from [this site](https://vk6ysf.com/balun_guanella_current_1-1.htm): -

[image]

**Simple Simulation**

[image]